# Freshly configured OpenAm console hangs when attempted to login

Tags: openam

I recently configured OpenAm (v13.0) following this vendor documentaion https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/getting-started. My user agent url is A) http://www.example.com:8000/ and my OpenAm url is B) http://openam.example.com:9090/openam. When I access my agent url, A, my OpenAm web Agent successfully redirect to my OpenAm url, B, as it supposes work.

However when tries to login as user 'demo' and password 'changeit' as instructed in the documentaion, the page hangs and it repeated try to the console url in rapid successions as shown in the following image.

My hunch is, user agent is working fine but the fault must be with some configuration of the OpenAm console. Can you suggest what needs to changed in OpenAm console?

Thanks..

[image]

Comment: What do you have configured as cookie domain? Sounds like you are trying to set up CDSSO, maybe you've missed a few settings in the agent profile?

Comment: Thanks @PeterMajor for the comment. As for cookie domain, this what I have defined in my hosts file.  127.0.0.1    localhost openam.example.com www.example.com.

Comment: A cookie domain is not related to any setting in your hosts file.

When you want to use 'localhost' for OpenAM you need to use host-based cookies (no entry for cookie domains in platform service) and you also need to tell OpenAM that it has to handle 'localhost' either because the instance URL is using 'localhost' or via fqdn mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I have made a mistake while configuring OpenAm. It is imperative to use the URL, 'http://openam.example.com:9090/openam/'. My mistake was, I've configured OpenAm in the URL http://localhost:9090/openam/.

This is emphasised in the documenation, under the point, 1.4.3. Here is the link,
https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/getting-started#install-openam

Looks like it is very useful for newbies when they're configuring OpenAm.

Comment: I faced the same issue, can u tell me where exactly did you changed the configuration ? Thanks